# Zend routing issue on legacy code

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have an issue with routing on a legacy Zend application I inherited - wondering if someone can help me debug?

So far I've checked:

- application.config.php - modules are loaded correctly:

  ```
  'modules' => array(
  'App',
  'Finding',
  'Listing',
  ```

and so on

- module.config.php and the route seems to be ok for the path, for example:

  ```
  'listing' => array(
          'type'    => 'segment',
          'options' => array(
              'route'    => '/admin/property/listing[/:action[/:id]][/:component/:optionTitle/:optionValue]',
              'constraints' => array(
                                                                          'action'                 => '[a-z0-9_-]*',
                                                                          'id'                     => '[0-9]+',
                                                                          'component'              => '[a-z0-9_-]*',
                                                                          'optionTitle'    => '[a-z0-9_-]*',
                                                                          'optionValue'   => '[a-z0-9_-]*'
                                                                  ),

              'defaults' => array(
                  'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Listing',
                  'action'     => 'list',
              ),
          ),
      ),
  ```

The actual error message I get back is:

```
     The requested URL could not be matched by routing. No Exception available
```

What I'm doing is in a user logged in area, clicking on a listing category which loads ok, and then submitting a POST form which updates specific attributes in the DB associated with that ID.

However on submit I get the above message, any further ways to track this down, if it's not a route issue?

EDIT

Comments don't really look that good for debug stuff, so I'll add them here, as requested:

Post data array:

```
   [listingId] => 121 [colvalues] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 33 [3] => 44 [4] => 55 [5] => 66 [6] => 77 [7] => 88 )
```

Individual URL structure

```
    admin/property/listing/view/11111
```

It's posting BACK to the same URL - so:

```
    admin/property/listing/view
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL you're POSTing to, and a full set of the POST data that's causing it to fail?

Comment: It's an internal application, however the URL structure is as follows:

Individual item edit URL: admin/property/listing/view/11111

It's posting BACK to the same URL - so:

admin/property/listing/view

Comment: Post debug values:

 [listingId] => 121
            [colvalues] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 22
                    [2] => 33
                    [3] => 44
                    [4] => 55
                    [5] => 66
                    [6] => 77
                    [7] => 88
                )

Comment: Check if there is another extra slash in the end when you browser is sending those requests.

Answer (score 0):

The route has an optional `id` parameter

`/admin/property/listing[/:action[/:id]]`

You are not posting an `id` parameter, but rather `listingId`.

My *guess(es)* are:

1. There is no `viewAction` in `Admin\Controller\Listing`.
2. There is controller logic that specifically checks for the `id` parameter and if not provided returns a response with a `404` status code.

The reason I think these are the causes is because even with the `id` parameter being missing in your route (`admin/property/listing/view`) the router should still match the controller action (as `id` is an *optional* parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the analysis.

The code does have a viewaction within the controller as:

`public function ViewAction()
        {
                $listingId = $this->params('id');
.... `
The ID is passed onto the next page so when on the listing page and I click to view -> I get the URL 

`admin/property/listing/view/11111`

And this works fine -- however when I amend some items within a form post -- it provides the error, so trying different debug solutions always helps!

Comment: @Poiro My point is that according to your route you need `id` but your post data has `listingId`, is this not the case?